# How to add prebuild activity in MSbuild to verify signing process?

Tags: msbuild, wix, wix3.5, strongname, msbuild-4.0

We are using Msbuild to build our Wix projects. Due to various issues , few times assemblies specified in wix were just delay signed. When it was installed in GAC it failed.

Is there any way to verify strong name signing verification as prebuild activity in wix?

I am using `sn -vf "assembly"` to do strong name verification.

I want to do strong name verification only for dlls which will be packed inside wix msi( in other words, assemblies specified in wxs file)

How to do it msbuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A quick solution is adding a **BeforeBuild** event that calls sn.exe:

Open your `.wixproj` file and add:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyToSign Include="C:\SignedAssembly1.dll"/>
    <AssemblyToSign Include="C:\SignedAssembly2.dll"/>      
</ItemGroup>
     <Exec Command="sn -q -vf %(AssemblyToSign.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

This will fail your build once an assembly fails verification.

---

- Another solution is use MSBuild Extension Pack's **[Signing](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.2.0/html/6371e887-86da-e49a-0c7f-4e3645663b6c.htm)** class:

Once again, this will fail your build on failed verification:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyToSign Include="C:\SignedAssembly1.dll"/>
        <AssemblyToSign Include="C:\SignedAssembly2.dll"/>      
</ItemGroup>
 <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Signing 
         TaskAction="Sign" 
         ToolPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin" 
         KeyFile="D:\key.snk" 
         Assemblies="@(AssemblyToSign)" />
</Target>
```

In order to use it you must add a reference to the Extension Pack assembly:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ExtensionTasksPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Common')">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Common</ExtensionTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(ExtensionTasksPath)\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll" TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Signing"/>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for the nice information. But usually in build, people won't directly change the project file. They will have separate script in which they will mention the list of wixproj.Number of wixproj to be build for project may be huge and editing each file is not practical

Comment: I provided a possible solution. Certainly you can take the BeforeBuild part to your main build script.

Comment: thanks buddy. I will try and when i complete that you can add it as part of answer. Once i tested it i will accept it as an answer

Comment: Buddy, In this case i need to specify each and every dll. Wxs file will have list of dlls to be part of the msi. That needs to be obtained through build script and it should be verified.

Comment: You need to parse the wxs, look for the `File` elements and record all the `Source` values. You can use PowerShell http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2007/12/02/parsing-xml-files-with-powershell.